# Get new users compared to yesterday

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a user traffic table where I need to get the gain/loss of new users  compared to the previous day. Just wondering if there is a better way to do this rather than the below solution.

Schema :-

```
Table Strcutre: Session_ID, session_day, user_id, product_id
```

What I have tried?

```
SELECT session_day,
       session_count,
       user_count - LAG( user_count, 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY session_day ) AS gain_loss_users
  FROM   
    (
        SELECT session_day,
               COUNT( session_id ) AS session_count,
               COUNT( user_id ) user_count
          FROM user_traffic
         GROUP BY session_day
     ) X ;
```

Comment: Looks pretty solid to me...

Comment: What identifies a customer as "new" or as "lost" - based only on the four table columns you presented?

Comment: There is no other way to identify whether the user is for the first time or a returning user.. The portion "new" in the question confuses me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to resolve "new" and "returning" persons problem. Here is my attempt:

```
    select session_day, 
       COUNT( distinct user_id ) AS user_cnt,
       count(distinct user_id) - lag(count(distinct user_id)) 
                                     over (order by session_day) gain,
       count(newu) AS  newu, count(returnu) AS returnu
  from (
          select session_id,
                 session_day,
                 user_id, 
                 CASE WHEN
                 count(*) over ( partition by user_id ORDER BY session_day,session_id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
                           = 1 
                      THEN 1
                  END 
                  AS newu,
                 CASE WHEN 
                 lag( session_day,1 ) over ( partition by user_id ORDER BY session_day,session_id ) 
                           <> 
                           lag( session_day,1 ) over ( order by session_day,session_id ) 
                      THEN 1
                 END  AS returnu    
            from user_traffic u
        )
  group by session_day
  order by session_day;
```

Test data and output:

```
create table user_traffic (session_id number(6), session_day date, 
                           user_id number(6), product_id number(6));

insert into user_traffic values (  1, date '2016-09-07', 101, 1);
insert into user_traffic values (  2, date '2016-09-07', 101, 4);
insert into user_traffic values (  3, date '2016-09-07', 102, 1);
insert into user_traffic values (  4, date '2016-09-08', 101, 2);
insert into user_traffic values (  5, date '2016-09-08', 101, 4);
insert into user_traffic values (  6, date '2016-09-09', 102, 1);
insert into user_traffic values (  7, date '2016-09-10', 102, 1);
insert into user_traffic values (  8, date '2016-09-10', 103, 3);

SESSION_DAY        CNT       GAIN        NEW    RETURNS
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2016-09-07           2                     2          0   -- 101 & 102 are new
2016-09-08           1         -1          0          0
2016-09-09           1          0          0          1   -- 102 returned
2016-09-10           2          1          1          0   -- 103 is new
```

Comment: This looks close to good. But would like to an addition to your answer.  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW. Not sure which db you are using to generate this output.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a *better* way, but there is a more concise way.  You can mix window functions with aggregation functions:

```
   SELECT session_day,
          COUNT(session_id ) as session_count,
          COUNT(DISTINCT user_id ) as user_count,
          (COUNT(DISTINCT user_id ) - 
           LAG(COUNT(DISTINCT user_id )) OVER (ORDER BY session_day)
          ) as gain_loss_users
      FROM user_traffic
     GROUP BY session_day;
```

I assume you want `COUNT(DISTINCT)` because (1) a user could have multiple sessions on the same day and (2) the two counts would be the same (if `user_id` and `session_id` are never `NULL`).

Comment: need to remove "PARTITION BY session_day" from the LAG() it shouldn't be partitioned because it is the order by and the query is already grouping on it.  If left in the lag result is NULL in sql-sever anyway

Comment: How can I get the numbers for gain and loss in new users?

Comment: @SOaddict . . . You can ask another question, with sample data and desired results.